# SMTP authentication vs non-authentication

Tags: authentication, smtp, send

I'm coding an SMTP Server here and wondering an issue which I don't know how to proceed.

You know that when you using Outlook, ThunderBird or any email client to send email, we need (the most of times) username and password to authenticate with the SMTP Server. In this case, SMTP Server requires an "AUTH LOGIN" before other commands such as MAIL, DATA...

I completed this stub in my project. But I'm wondering about a case, when another SMTP Client send directly to my SMTP Server. I mean our server is the final destination of the email. In this case, the authentication with AUTH LOGIN should not be required.

How can I organize my code for 2 cases above. How does the professional MTA such as Postfix, PowerMTA, Exim organize for these.

I hope you will help me

Comment: So an "*only require authentication for non-local mail*" option?

Comment: This wikipedia article might be of interest: [SMTP Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP_Authentication)

Comment: I think I have only one way as Alex K said above. But I got difficulty in an issue: In the most case AUTH LOGIN is executed before RCPT TO command which we may determine if it's a local or external address. This mean I am still confused in this.

Answer (score 0):

Most outgoing SMTP servers do one of the following:

1)  Require SMTP Authentication

2)  Alllow relaying without SMTP Authentication only from clients within a certain IP range

If you are doing neither of the above, then that means that your SMTP server is basically operating as an 'open relay', meaning that spammers can abuse your server to send outgoing spam mail.

Many ISP-hosted SMTP servers do #2 above, to allow their clients (and only their clients) to send mail through their SMTP server - as long as the client is on their network.